# Getting values from multiple instances of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a small project where I have a graph with 12 nodes, the user assigns values to each node with a dropdown menu. Since I didn't want to repeat code I found a loop in written in jquery that clones the dropdown menu as many times as I need. However, when coupled with a javascript function showData to display selected values, I get an error that the array is undefined. I suspect it has to do with how the jquery function appends clones to the unordered list since the showData function works just fine on one instance of the dropdown menu. That being said, I'm unsure how to proceed. Here is the code I'm working with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div class = "menu">
<form name="nodeForm">  
<ul>
    <li class="template">Node <span class="qnum">1</span>:
        <select id="select" onchange="showData()">
            <option value="" disabled selected>select a note for this node</option>
            <option val="1">"A"</option>
            <option val="2">"A# / B♭"</option>
            <option val="3">"B"</option>
            <option val="4">"C"</option>
            <option val="5">"C# / D♭"</option>
            <option val="6">"D"</option>
            <option val="7">"D# / E♭"</option>
            <option val="8">"E"</option>
            <option val="9">"F"</option>
            <option val="10">"F# / G♭"</option>
            <option val="11">"G"</option>
            <option val= "12"> "G# / A♭"</option>           
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<p id="firstP">&nbsp;</p>


<script> 

//jquery for 12 node dropdown
    $(function() {
    var $ul = $("ul"),
        $li = $ul.find("li.template"),
        i;

    for (i=2; i <= 12; i++)
        $li.clone().appendTo($ul).find("span.qnum").text(i);
    var v = $("#select").val(); //trying to get data with jquery 
    console.log(v);
});

//getting the data with js
function showData() 
    {
        var theSelect = nodeForm.select;
        var firstP = document.getElementById('firstP');
        var secondP = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        var thirdP = theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].text;

        firstP.innerHTML = ('This option\'s index number is: ' + theSelect.selectedIndex + ' (Javascript index numbers start at 0)');   
    }


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in duplicating your template, you now have 12 select elements that all have the same id, "select".  So "theSelect" is getting set to an array, and thus theSelect.selectedIndex is undefined.

In the onchange event you can get the element that is affected and then use that:

```
<select id="select" onchange="showData(event)">
```

...

```
function showData(e) 
{
    var index = e.target.selectedIndex;
    firstP.innerHTML = ('This option\'s index number is: ' + index + ' (Javascript index numbers start at 0)');   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

html:

```
<ul></ul>
```

javascript:

```
let html = '';

for (let i = 1; i <= 12; ++i) {
  html+= `
  <li>Node <span class="qnum">${i}</span>:
    <select>
      <option>select a note for this node</option>
      <option val="1">"A"</option>
      <option val="2">"A# / B♭"</option>
      <option val="3">"B"</option>
      <option val="4">"C"</option>
      <option val="5">"C# / D♭"</option>
      <option val="6">"D"</option>
      <option val="7">"D# / E♭"</option>
      <option val="8">"E"</option>
      <option val="9">"F"</option>
      <option val="10">"F# / G♭"</option>
      <option val="11">"G"</option>
      <option val= "12"> "G# / A♭"</option>           
    </select>
    <span>(index selected is <span class="selected">0</span>)</span>
  </li>`;
  }

  $('ul').append(html);

  $('select').on('change', function() {
     $(`span.selected:eq(${$('select').index(this)})`).text(this.options.selectedIndex)
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/47bcvvn2/2/

`.clone()` tends to run into weird problems. Instead, this generates the html as a whole and then adds that to the DOM.

`$('select').index(this)` - this returns the index of the select changed, based on all of the selects available. You could give a collection of selects a class if you want to narrow it down and be able to use other selects elsewhere.

`this.options.selectedIndex` - this returns the index of the option selected, regardless which select it's from. Since 
`this` is the select that fired the `change` event.